Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler' to type 'System.Web.UI.Page in ASP.NET MVC controller
I'm trying to get the current page from view in controller, but the code throws the error shown below.
Home controller:
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // throws Null
    Page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;

    // throws error
    Page = (System.Web.UI.Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    var model = DeviceLoginManager.GetOnlineDevices();

    return View(model);
}

Error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler' to type 'System.Web.UI.Page in MVC controller

I need get same page or alternatives for System.Web.UI.Page in ASP.NET MVC.


System.Web.UI.Page is Webforms, not MVC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page?view=netframework-4.8.1

need alternatives for Page 'HttpContext.Handler' as Page  also using but it returns null

In ASP.NET MVC, you do not have pages - you have views. There's no alternative for the old ASP.NET webforms pages - you just cannot get that. The question really is more: WHY do you want to get a page? What are you trying to do with that page?

i need to pass in class library sdk method contains Page  public void ExecuteCommand(System.Web.UI.Page page, XmlDocument request, DeviceResponseHandler responseHandler, ExceptionHandler responseExceptionHandler)
{//work}

Is this class library something you wrote? It appears to have a hard dependency on Web Forms, and thus needs to be updated to not have that dependency.
